# Result does not return full array but single value

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to create a function to shift `t` rows up from an array. Everything works except the result returns a single value.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer) As Variant
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer
Dim A() As Variant
Dim nrow As Integer

nrow = rng.Rows.Count
n = n Mod nrow

ReDim A(nrow) As Variant

For i = 1 To nrow
t = (i + n) Mod nrow
If t = 0 Then t = nrow
A(i) = rng(t)
Next i

ShiftVector = A

End Function
```

All value in output array return exactly one value of the number of row shift.

Comment: Can you explain what the function does ? what do you mean by t rows up ? Will be better if you can put an example in the question.

Comment: If you want to have results of this function in a column then change `A` to 2d array: `ReDim A(nrow, 1 To 1) As Variant`.